# AR Multiplayer Game Sync PUN2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, multiplayer, photon

I can not synchronize another objects in GameScene such as enemies. When MasterClient set the game area in another place other than default objects are moving anywhere, sometimes i can see them out of the game area. If game area is in the default place everything is okey.

I need to fix that issue. Please help me immediately.

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (!photonView.IsMine)
    {
        rb.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(rb.position, networkedPosition, Vector3.Distance(rb.position, networkedPosition) * (1.0f / PhotonNetwork.SerializationRate));
    }
}
public void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
{
    if (stream.IsWriting)
    {
        stream.SendNext(rb.position - battleArenaGameobject.transform.position);
    }
    else
    {
        networkedPosition = (Vector3)stream.ReceiveNext() + battleArenaGameobject.transform.position;
        if (Vector3.Distance(rb.position, networkedPosition) > teleportIfDistanceGreaterThan)
        {
            rb.position = networkedPosition;
        }
    }
}
```